# Extract and add link to URLs in string

Tags: javascript, regex, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

I have several strings that have links in them. For instance:

```
var str = "I really love this site: http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

and I need to add a link tag to that so the str will be:

```
I really love this site: <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">http://www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

I imagine there would be some regex involved, but I can't get it to work for me with match(). Any other ideas

Comment: Simple regular expressions are a naive approach to this problem and will fail a lot of tests for edge cases. When detecting URLs, it's **ALWAYS** better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).

Comment: I created this library that might help anyone looking for a solution in this page: http://ali-saleem.github.io/anchorme.js/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's easy:

```
str.replace( /(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/gi , '<a href="$1">$1</a>' )
```

Output:

```
I really love this site: <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">http://www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: The code above will fail a lot of tests for edge cases. When detecting URLs, it's **ALWAYS** better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).

Comment: @DanDascalescu I agree

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: thank you! BTW/OT: any chance to consider [this reopen request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/823898/when-to-use-visual-diffing-vs-unified-diff-patch-files) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856097/how-can-i-check-javascript-code-for-syntax-errors-only-from-the-command-line)? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
function replaceURL(val) {
  var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return val.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

Comment: +1 for the elaborate regex. didn't know js had the \b marker or I would have used it

Comment: The code above will fail a lot of tests for edge cases. When detecting URLs, it's **ALWAYS** better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a quick and dirty Regular Expression based solution. Something on the lines of

```
RegExp exp = new RegExp('(.*)(http://[^ ])(.*)', 'g'); // matches URLs
string = string.replace(exp, $1 + '<a href=\"' + $2 + '\">' + $2 '</a>' + $3);
```

I haven't tested it yet though, so needs some refining.

Comment: Regular expressions like that will fail a lot of tests for edge cases. When detecting URLs, it's **ALWAYS** better to rely on a specialized library. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21925491/1269037).